# Cleaning form data in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, slug

How can i clean and modify data from a form in django. I would like to define it on a per field basis for each model, much like using ModelForms.

What I want to achieve is automatically remove leading and trailing spaces from defined fields, or turn a title (from one field) into a slug (which would be another field).

Comment: How did you get leading or trailing spaces in the field?  Do your users type that kind of thing?  Or are you talking about making a "cleaning" pass on data you've loaded some other way?  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define clean_FIELD_NAME() methods which can validate and alter data, as documented here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation

Comment: Also the overall clean() method of the Form.